# Why js function works inside of another function but not alone

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these two functions below and for whatever reason the windowedBox function only works when I call it from another function. If I directly call windowedBox(), it wont do anything. If I call getShareButtons(), it calls windowedBox() and works correctly. If anyone knows why this is happening, please help me. :(

NOTE:: if you're wondering why it says $j and not $ its because i set it up that way.

```
function getShareButtons(){
    var postPath = window.location.pathname;
    var videoTitle = 'asdf';
    var videoURL = 'asdf';

    //Output social button attributes
    $j(".facebook-share").attr('href', 'asdf');
    windowedBox(); <---THIS CALL WORKS
}

function windowedBox() { 
    $j(".facebook-share, .twitter-share").click(function(){
        window.open(this.href, videoTitle, "width=626, height=436", "status=0", "toolbar=0");
        return false;
    });
}
```

Comment: `this.href`. what is `this` in the 2nd function?

Comment: `windowedBox(); <---THIS CALL WORKS` That shouldn't work, you should be getting a `ReferenceError` for `videoTitle` either way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this is because you are using the variable

```
videoTitle
```

which is not declared in this function but in the other one :)

Comment: @EvgeniyNaydenov I cant yet. have to wait 5 minutes... D:

Answer (score 2):

You're getting an error because in the first function the link `href` attribute is being set, but if you call just the second one then the `this.href` stays undefined or empty

try it like this

```
$j(".facebook-share").attr('href', 'asdf');
var videoTitle = 'Title';

windowedBox();

function windowedBox() { 
    $j(".facebook-share, .twitter-share").click(function(){
        window.open(this.href, videoTitle, "width=626, height=436", "status=0", "toolbar=0");
        return false;
    });
}
```

Comment: `this.href` is not undefined, but an empty string. And `window.open('');` should open the window anyway. The problem may be caused by `ReferenceError` because `videoTitle` variable probably is not defined.

Comment: @EvgeniyNaydenov we don't know if it's an empty string or not. If the links looks like `<a>link</a>` before the manipulation - then it's undefined

Comment: The link is setup so that if JS isn't available i still have a basic url in place. I fixed the variable issue and that fixed the problem. Thank you everyone :)

Comment: @ZoltanToth even more, `window.open(undefined);` will open new window.

Comment: @EvgeniyNaydenov You're correct. Even with non-present href attribute it returns it as a `String`, which is somewhat odd

Comment: It's not odd. In HTMLAnchorElement's interface property `href` has a type of `DOMString` which is mapped to `String` type directly. [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLAnchorElement)